# ASP.net forms auth and timing out

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have a small simple problem, however the following is quite lengthy to explain the issue more.

I have an MVC 4 application using forms authentication. I have it setup using browser session cookies so that they can use the site for as long as they want, but as soon as they close the browser it in essence logs them out.

Now I have added an extra layer of security in the form of an idle timer, so that if they are idle for, say, 5 minutes, an ajax request is sent to the server to delete the forms auth token, return a session expired partial view, and show this session expired view as a modal dialog.

This dialog has a label that shows the users name, and a password input field so they can re-enter their password.

What this means is that if anyone opens up another session they will just go to the login screen as no-one is logged in, and teh same happens if they just refresh teh current screen. But it also means that if the user enters their password on the timeout screen the dialog sends an ajax request to the server to login them in again, and then just removes the dialog.

This all works (mostly) perfectly and they will be on the same screen as they were before, and they will also have everything filled out as they did before for example if they were in the middle of filling out a large form etc.

**The issue is**, if they have 2 different tabs open in their browser, the first one times out, shows the timeout screen with their name and the password entry box as expected, but the 2nd browser tab when it makes the request for the time-out screen to the mvc method, does not find a logged in user, as no-one is logged in as the person was logged out with the first time-out request. How can I get round this problem? Is there a simple solution? Or is there a better design for how I am doing this?

Comment: Well, when the seconds screen finds that there is no session it can show your dialog again, after that it can periodically check if the session has come back and then simply close the dialog again?

Comment: but say for talking sake the user has 2 screens, 1 main screen open and another screen they forgot about...the screen they forgot about times-out, signs them out, and shows the time-out dialog, and then the main screen they are working on makes the same request to timeout, there is no logged in user, and that screen becomes useless to them to try and sign back in

Comment: I usually solve this by tracking users activity on the serverside, so we check when the users last action was (Stored in fx Session) when the "timeout" call from client comes in, if its less than five minutes he must be doing something on another screen and we tell client to not time him out and to "call us back" to see if we should time him out at that point

Comment: what is "fx session"? I think regardless, with your solution the same end result would happen, you have 2 tabs open, leave them both for 10 minutes, and one of them would time-out correctly, the other wouldn't as the user is signed out.

Comment: miracledev's scenario makes sense. Before you log user out, please check 'LastActivityDate/LastLoginDate' column.

Comment: By session i mean store the users last activity as a timestamp on the serverside. And then i don't see why you can't show the dialog if the users is logged out, you now that users calling your specific "Logout" action using AJAX have been logged in, hence show them the relogin dialog box if they are no longer logged in?

Comment: I think I must be missing something here. If the user has been logged out, then the forms auth cookie would have been removed, so when the user attempts to do anything, or the next timeout request has been made, the server does not have any details for the person, who they were logged in as etc.....

Comment: To me, having a last activity stored on the server only works to stop one tab timing out if they are using another tab...but if they have 2 tabs that have been left for half an hour, they would both have timed out, and only one of those would have timed out properly and logged out, the 2nd would have attempted to call the logout, but would not have passed any details for the person as they wont be stored in the cookies anymore

Comment: In the recieving end of an AJAX call to timeout and user, i imagine some code like this:

if(User.IsAuthenticated){ //Check last activity on server}else{ //Show relogin dialog }

The whole point is. If the user is logged out and you call an AJAX call to try to time him out then he must have been logged in before hence we show him the "relogin" dialog

Comment: Fair enough, but the point I was making, was if the user makes the ajax call the 2nd time, we cant show the "relogin" as when the server side gets all the markup for the relogin, the logged in user would be blank and couldnt pre-populate the markup with the login username...they would then need to manually enter their login username which is something I do wish to allow, all they can enter is the password

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue in live sites and it's really annoying. It forces users to only have one tab open to avoid getting logged out.

Could you solve it by not logging the user out on the server once the timeout hits, but only delete the session cookie? That way the user will still see the timeout screen on the idle tab, but can still work with the other tab. It can still be an inconvenience, but I think if you really want that timeout screen it might be the way to do it. Unless you want to do it with WebSockets or something similar.

Comment: But if I was to delete the cookie, that in essence is logging them out, if the first time-out request hits the server, deletes the cookie, then the 2nd tab makes a time-out request it won't send a cookie, and will hit the server as if it is a new user?